# Which arguments should I use to open file in new tab in Xamarin studio?

Tags: windows, unity-game-engine, xamarin, arguments

I'm using Xamarin studio with Unity3D as external editor, but when I just open file in with "filename" argument, Xamarin opens new window.
Is it possible to open new tab instead? (which will be file passed in arguments)

Something like:

```
Xamarin -file myscript.cs -line 23
```

Comment: Windows or macOS?

Comment: Windows, but I supposed it will work on both. (added tag)

Comment: Why not just use the default mono-develop? See [MonoDevelop](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MonoDevelop.html).

Comment: @zwcloud , It's crashing on my PC constantly. Reinstalling it does not work and nobody knows how to solve that problem.

Comment: You can try [vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/unity) instead. If Xamarin Studio cannot debug your code, then vscode should be the best alternative. But if you're developing your project on Windows, use [Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn940019.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but there are reasons I asked question about Xamarian rather than about suggesting an editor for me. Sorry if "Unity3D" tag mislead you to believe in the later, I just thought it would help.